# pointer changes the whole matrix

Tags: python, pointers, matrix

I'm tring to make a matrix but it makes always pointers..

I want the code to make every cell to it's own but it makes pointer for each other in the lines:

```
mat = [ ["X"]*10 ]*10
for line in mat:
    print line

['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
mat[0][0] = "O"
for line in mat:
    print line

['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the lists on each row are actually the same. When you do the modification in

```
mat[0][0] = "O"
```

The list you're modifying is the same that appears on all of the rows. You should create the matrix using something like:

```
mat = [["X" for x in range(10)] for y in range (10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = [['X'] * 10 for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `*` operator just repeats the list however many times you specify. This is not a copy in the way you might expect, it's more like creating a list of references.

when you do something like `b = [a]*2` what you get as a result is actually `[[a[0],a[1],...],[a[0],a[1],...]]`, so any change to `a` here changes `b`.

For example:

```
>>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>> b = [a]*3
>>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>> a[0] = 999
>>>> b
[[999, 2, 3], [999, 2, 3], [999, 2, 3]]
```

To get this to work with the syntax you have used you must tell python to copy the list.

```
>>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>> b = deepcopy([a]*3)
>>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>> a[0] = 999
>>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

[deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) will actually copy everything in the way in which you expect.